# Solutions to $y’(t)=y(t+C)$ or more generally $y’(t)=y(g(t))$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Was wondering if there were solutions to the above differential equation(s), because I couldn’t find a name for them online, let alone any theory. Some more specific $g(t)$: $t^2$, $2t$, and of course anything you can say in general would be interesting. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in [Delay equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_differential_equation). However, you may not have well-posedness for problems where $t < g(t)$ when you are given initial data $y(0)$.

Comment: Initial data is not localized to a point, usually one needs to give a history on the whole segment from $t_0$ to $t_1=g(t_0)$.

Answer (score -1):

use chain rule:
$y'(t)=y(g(t))\\
\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{dy}{dg}\frac{dg}{dt}$

Thus the solution is the integral:

$y(t)=\int{y(g(t))g'(t)dt}+C$

Comment: The chain rule does not work this way. Try to write this properly with compositions of functions, it is not possible.